# optimality conditions

Tags: optimization

there is a Theorem If  x is a local optimum to (G) then there is no feasible descent direction at x.

(G) min f(x)

I want to know if the reverse of theorem is true or not, that means if there is no feasible descent direction at x, then x is local optimum?

Comment: well, its basically the definition of a local minimum $f(x^*) \le f(y)$ $\forall y \in U_\epsilon(x^*)$.

Comment: If you have equality constraints then the set of feasible directions may be empty at every feasible point.

Comment: Thank you @ A.Γ. That is true but I want to know about unconstrained problem. I asked from my instructor today and the answer is that converse of theorem does not hold. now I want an example.

Comment: For unconstrained problem *all* directions are feasible, and the converse is true. How do you define a feasible descent direction?